# Add a file to a list of already opened files in vim

Tags: vim

If I already editing multiple files in vim(1), how to open one more file so it is added as next and become one from the list of the opened files?

Comment: See `:help :next`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the `:argadd {name}` command. Without a prepended `[count]`, the `{name}` is added just after the current entry in the argument list, so `:next` will switch to it.